# Django + Celery logging: custom handler works in main process but not celery worker process

Tags: python, django, logging, celery

There are alot of resources on this topic but none of them worked unfortunately.

1. Here is my django setting for logging:

   ```
   LOGGING = {
   "version": 1,
   "disable_existing_loggers": False,
   "formatters": {
       "default": {
           "format": "[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s] [%(name)s] %(message)s"
       }
   },
   "filters": {"require_debug_false": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse"}},
   "handlers": {
       "console": {
           "level": "INFO",
           "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
           "formatter": "default",
       },
       "mail_admins": {
           "level": "ERROR",
           "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
           "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
       },
       "my_custom_handler": {
           "level": "INFO",
           "class": "my_custom_handler_class",
       },
   },
   "loggers": {
       "django.request": {
           "handlers": ["mail_admins"],
           "level": "ERROR",
           "propagate": True,
       },
       "": {
           "handlers": ["console", "my_custom_handler"],
           "level": "INFO",
           "propagate": True,
           "formatter": "default",
       },
       "celery": {
           "handlers": ["console", "my_custom_handler"],
           "level": "INFO",
           "propagate": True,
       },
   },
   ```

   }
2. Celery is initialized before base.py is imported/settings are initialized (which may be the culprit) and the logger I use for logging in the celery task is

   `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`
3. I tried setting `CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False`, use the after_setup_task_logger signal (I tried printing to see if that signal is dispatched at all but it isn't) and none of them had any effect
4. I tried using `setup_logging` which kind of worked:

   ```
   @setup_logging.connect
   def config_loggers(*args, **kwags):
      my_handler = MyCustomHandler()
      root_logger = logging.getLogger()
      root_logger.addHandler(my_handler)
      root_logger.level = logging.INFO


   @worker_process_init.connect
   def init_worker(**kwargs):
       logger = get_task_logger(__name__) # or Logger.get_logger(__name__), no difference

       logger.info("My log message")
   ```

and I say it kind of worked only because when I inspect the logger object's **root** in `init_worker` I see the handler is there but it's not in the logger's handler and it doesn't seem to propagate (i.e I don't see the log message) .. only if I attach the handler to the logger object directly that I can see the message but obviously the problem with that is I have to attach the handler every time I declare a logger in a new file which does not make sense.

Comment: fwiw, I noticed that `setup_logging` runs in the main process while `worker_process_init` runs in the worker process, so it could be that handlers added to the main process aren't reachable from the worker process and hence I don't see the message?

Comment: Why are you specifying `celery` as a key in loggers? Assuming it's Django that the celery workers are running, you only need to specify Django loggers, and then you get the loggers working regardless whether it's run in Gunicorn or Daphne or Celery.

Comment: Also, can you show in your question how you initiate your logger before using it?

Comment: the `celery` logger now has no effect, so I can totally remove it.

Comment: edited the question to show how the logger is initialized (this is done in every file separately)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong with it. I have a similar config, and it works out of the box. Are both console logging and your customer handler not working?

Comment: console works fine (which is the default without adding any extra config), custom does not

Comment: Can you show how your custom logger looks like? Maybe the issue is in that class.

Comment: could you show your startup command of your celery workers?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default Celery `worker_pool` option of `prefork` then if your custom handler does something which isn't "fork safe" (like starting a thread) then the forked worker child processes won't behave as expected.

For example `fluent-logger` provides `fluent.asynchandler.FluentHandler` which creates an asyncsender which starts a thread - if this has been started in the parent celery process then forked child processes think they don't need to start one but actually the thread got killed on fork.

This means any logging from child processes won't get sent and eventually the fluent-logger queue gets full and either blocks or discards.

See [this issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-python/issues/60#issuecomment-1645564425) for more details.